# JSON nested table

Tags: ajax, json, getjson

How can I read a nested json with ajax?

I have a json formatted by php after a sql request as follow :

```
[
 {
 "owner_info":
     {
     "name":"John",
     "address":"4",
     "date":"10/01/2012"
     }
  },
  {
  "telephone":    
      [
          {
             "id":"1",
             "place":"5",
             "number":"+123456"
          },
          {
             "id":"2",
             "place":"5",
             "number":"+789456"
          },
          {
             "id":"3",
             "place":"8",
             "number":"+0011223"
          },
      ]
   }
]
```

Ajax do a classic

```
$.getJSON(script, function (result) {
    $(result).each(function(i){     
        // do something with result     
    });
});
```

I tried :

```
result[i].owner_info.name -> error
result[i].telephone[0].id -> error
```

I have been searching on the internet but can't find any solution...

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong `each` method. `$(selector).each()` is not the same as `$.each()`!

From the jQuery documentation.

> The `$.each()` function is not the same as `$(selector).each()`, which is
>   used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object. The `$.each()`
>   function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is a
>   map (JavaScript object) or an array.

A solution using the correct `each` function.

```
$.getJSON(script, function (result) {
    $.each(result, function(key, value) {
        // either use
        console.log(value.owner_info.name);
        // or
        console.log(result[key].owner_info.name);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks but i still get the same error in javascript : 
owner_info.name is null or not an object
is there something wrong with nesting json like that ?

Comment: Then `result` is not in the format you specified! I create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F2Ubf/) with the data you gave and it works!

Comment: I just realised that the part trying to read the telephone is the one firing the error.
 
I'm trying value.telephone[1].number but javascript error as above

Comment: Now after a second look on your data I see that your array contains 2 objects. One object is `owner_info` and the other object is `telephone`. From what you have tried it seems you want to have `telephone` be in the `owner_info` object, not the second element of the `result` array. The code above will also fail for the second element in the array because it has no property called `name`.

Comment: what i want to achieve is something like `[ owner_info, telephone[] ]` -> an entry has 1 owner_info and n telephone. How can I achieve that ?